Proposition I-3.5 in Hartshorne
The following is the statement of Proposition I-3.5 in Hartshorne.

Let $X$ be any variety and let $Y$ be an affine varietiy. Then there is a natural bijective mapping of sets$$\alpha:\text{Hom}(X,Y)\stackrel{\sim}{\longrightarrow}\text{Hom}(A(Y),\mathcal{O}(X))$$where the left Hom means morphisms of varieties, and the right Hom means homomorphisms of $k$-algebras.

My question here is how to use this proposition. In exercise 3.1, for example, I used this proposition in a way that " A variety $X$ is affine if and only if there exists an affine variety $Y$ such that $\mathcal{O}(X)\cong A(Y)$". However, I found this interpretation  false since $X=\mathbb{A}^2-\{(0,0)\}$ is not affine while $\mathcal{O}(X)\cong k[x,y]\cong A(\mathbb{A}^2)$ (exercise 3.6). What was wrong with my interpretation?

This proposition does not give a criterion for affineness. It just tells you that morphisms between affine varieties (which we already know are affine) are in bijective correspondence with maps between their coordinate rings.

You always have $\mathcal{O}(X)\simeq A({\rm Spm},\mathcal{O}(X))$ so your affineness criterion is completely false.

Ah, this proposition just provides us with a morphism as part of the proof. Now I understand. Thank you.
